# PHP For loop not initiating

Tags: php, mysql

```
$queryGetTop = ("SELECT id,name,address,port,vote,isspon FROM servers ORDER BY vote ASC LIMIT 10");
$actionGetTop = mysql_query($queryGetTop);
while ($rowGetTop = mysql_fetch_array($actionGetTop)) {
    $countGetTopname[] = $rowGetTop['name'];
    $countGetTopip[] = $rowGetTop['address'];
    $countGetTopvotes[] = $rowGetTop['vote'];
    $countGetTopspon[] = $rowGetTop['isspon'];
    $countGetTopport[] = $rowGetTop['port'];
    $countGetTopid[] = $rowGetTop['id'];
}

$length = count($countGetTopname);



for ($i = 0; $i > $length; $i++) {
    echo $i;

    /* echo"

      <tbody>
      <tr>
      <td><span "; if($countGetTopspon[$i] == "1"){echo "class=\"label label-important\">Sponsored</span>";}echo $countGetTopname[$i]."</td>
      <td>". $countGetTopip[$i] .":". $countGetTopport[$i] ."</td>
      <td>". $countGetTopvotes[$i] ."</td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
      "; */
}
```

I did some debugging and my arrays from MySQL get into the array. So I echo'd $i in the for loop and nothing printed, so the for loop is the problem. I'm not sure what I've done wrong the loop isn't printing any errors the table just doesnt get printed (when its not in the comment).

Comment: You need `$i < $length`... Or maybe even `$i <= $length`

Comment: Read this slowly... let `i` be 0, while `i` is **larger than** `$length`, ...

Comment: Also, I don't think you want <tbody> in the loop.

Comment: Your debugging procedure was OK. You understood that control never enters the loop body. Why stop there? There is only one reason that can cause this: the loop condition evaluates to `false` immediately. So look at the loop condition, the bug **must be** there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your [**`for(){}`**](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) loop to:

```
for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++ ){
  // execute this code
 }
```

the part `$i < $length;` is telling php: while `$length` is less than `$i` (which is set to zero first,) keep increment or (re-iterate through the loop)by one, meaning.. after `$i` gets incremented ***enough times***, and if it ever reaches equal to the number of `$length` the script should stop.

Comment: What's infinite about this?

Comment: Technically not an infinite loop as $i is always going to be 0, and the loop only runs if $i is bigger than $length, which it never will be.

Comment: it will be infinite only if $length < 0

Comment: @sasjaq `$length` could never be `< 0`... It's derived from `count()`

Comment: This loop can never be infinite no matter what `$i` and `$length` are due to integer overflow. It could only be infinite if it read e.g. `$i <= PHP_INT_MAX` (the equals in the condition has to be there).

Comment: @brbcoding i know, therefor it couldn't be infinite

Answer (score 0):

I hope the problem is

```
for ($i=0; $i > $length; $i++){
```

I think it will be

```
for ($i=0; $i<$length; $i++){
```

** As you are making `$i=0` and trying to check if `$length` is less then `$i`.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure why you're even doing two for-loops. It's hopelessly inefficient.
Here is how I'd do it. You're sure it'll loop through everything anyway.
I also think you have a bug with the , so I suggested a fix to that. Take what you want from it, but this is much cleaner than what you were attempting. Also, saving things in a variable rather than echoing constantly is helpful if other people are gonna be looking at your code.

```
$queryGetTop = ("SELECT id,name,address,port,vote,isspon FROM servers ORDER BY vote ASC LIMIT 10");
$actionGetTop = mysql_query($queryGetTop);
$str = '';
while($rowGetTop = mysql_fetch_array($actionGetTop)){
    $str .= '<tbody>';
    $str .= '<tr>';
    $str .= '<td>';
    if ($rowGetTop['isspon'] == "1") {
        $str .= '<span class="label label-important">Sponsored</span>';
    }
    $str .= $rowGetTop['name'];
    $str .= '</td><td>';
    $str .= $rowGetTop['address'] .':'. $rowGetTop['port'];
    $str .= '</td><td>';
    $str .= $rowGetTop['vote'];
    $str .= '</td></tr></tbody>';
}

echo $str;
```